# Implementing clang based code coverage in custom Bazel C rules

Tags: code-coverage, bazel, bazel-rules

I am trying to get `bazel coverage //my:test` to output coverage data files, building with custom C rules and using a custom clang toolchain.

For Bazel's native C rules this is a solved problem. I can build coverage output using the `cc_library` and `cc_test` native rules by running the following command with env set:

```sh
export BAZEL_USE_LLVM_NATIVE_COVERAGE=1
export GCOV=/path/to/llvm-profdata
export BAZEL_LLVM_COV=/path/to/llvm-cov
export CC=/path/to/clang

bazel coverage //my:test --experimental_generate_llvm_lcov --combined_report=lcov
```

The test target has a `coverage.dat` file output and there is a combined dat report file too. I have noticed that the `cc_library` target returns an `InstrumentedFilesInfo` provider that has the ["metadata files"](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/3.5.0/skylark/lib/InstrumentedFilesInfo.html#metadata_files) attribute populated with the `.gcno` files output during compilation.

---

I am using the `cc_common` Starlark library to build custom C rules and my compile action is setup via `cc_common.compile()`. While `*.gcno` files are outputs that Bazel expects from this action [0], the compile function does not return any `*.gcno` `File` objects in the compilation context or compilation output so using them as the inputs to another action/returning in a provider/adding to the target's runfiles is not possible.

I understand that the `.dat` files are produced using the `*.gcno` compile output and the `*.gcda` sandboxed test execution output and combined in the [collect_cc_coverage.sh](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/test/collect_cc_coverage.sh) script. Something in the plumbing of my rule implementation is missing that is not being fixed by returning a provider constructed by [`coverage_common.instrumented_files_info()`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/lib/coverage_common.html) and declaring extra outputs of `cc_common.compile()` is currently not possible.

[0]: Running under `coverage` rather than `test` has the toolchain feature where `--compile` is added the `.gcno` files are output and they appear in `bazel-out`.

### My questions:

- Has anyone had any experience implementing code coverage for custom C rules?
- How do I get my test executable to take in `.gcno` files, generate the `.gcda` files and combine the two using my toolchain to produce the `.dat` files that are expected with the native C rules? (This question does not require `.gcno` - solutions involving profraw/profdata are equally valid.)